# Клонировать диск с gparted

Tags: linux, fedora, ssd, partition, gparted

Хочу перенести систему со старого hdd(320GB) на ssd(275GB), по объему данных влезет.
Столкнулся с проблемой разбивки нового диска.
вывод fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3ADBB6B9-D132-427F-B2C5-9D3666CDB354

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    411647    409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sda2   411648   2508799   2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2508800 625141759 622632960 296.9G Linux LVM




Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-root: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-swap: 7.8 GiB, 8317304832 bytes, 16244736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-home: 239.1 GiB, 256779485184 bytes, 501522432 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

вывод parted -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  211MB   210MB   fat16        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      211MB   1285MB  1074MB  ext4
 3      1285MB  320GB   319GB                                      lvm
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как разбить в gparted(загрузился с live usb) новый ссд.

сделал 1 раздел на 210МБ fat16, один на 1250 МБ ext4, один lvm2pv на оставшееся место, ка дальше разбить этот lvm2pv на swap, root, home?
и как проставить флаги(и нужно ли это ?)

Comment: Открой в консоли `sudo gparted`, там все будет

Comment: @MickeyU, разделы то я создал, проблема в том как разбить lvm на нужные разделы

Comment: Флаги ставь boot , нужно, если ты будешь грузиться с этой системы

Comment: Swap у тебя сам появится

Comment: А просто 'dd'? После раздвинуть разделы.

Comment: @George, `parted` тут не поможет, лучше почитай какой-нить букварь по работе с lvm для начала ([первые](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/lvm) [три](http://xgu.ru/wiki/LVM) [ссылки](https://habr.com/ru/post/67283/) из гугла)... механический перенос томов — дело не благодарное, обычно в таких случаях добавляют новый раздел (физический том) в группу томов, а затем переносят на него логические тома (эти root/swap/home), после чего, при необходимости, отключают первый. Прелесть в том, что всё это обычно делается прямо из рабочей системы без загрузки со стороннего носителя...

Comment: @Fat-Zer спасибо, а можно чуть подробнее по поводу переноса с загруженной основной системы?
ссылки на толковое чтиво будет более чем достаточно

Comment: @George, Можешь просмотреть на xgu (вторая ссылка выше) «Добавление нового диска», а затем для перемещения данных на ssd смотри в сторону [pvmove](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ru-ru/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/logical_volume_manager_administration/online_relocation). У шляпы, кстати, хорошая документация по lvm... Теперь даже вполне достойный  русский перевод появился... оба этих ресурса могу посоветовать к ознакомлению...

Comment: да, кстати, т.к. ssd меньше жёсткого, то один из томов скорей всего придётся сжать (/home, вероятно), если у тебя там не что-то модное вроде btrfs, то для этого его всё же придётся отмонтировать...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, спасибо, буду пробовать.
у меня ext4